# How to format value as float with 2 deciaml only in mdx?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

Here is my value :

**VALUE -0,00398911382022891**

and member which count this value

```
         MEMBER [Date].[Percentage] AS 
              ([Date].[AverageSaleNumberThisYear] - [Date].[AverageSaleNumberPreviouseYear] )/ [Date].[AverageSaleNumberThisYear].
```

If I use  FORMAT_STRING = "Percent" I am getting this value : -0,40%, but i want exactly the same but without the `%` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx) in MDX.  It sounds like you want

```
FORMAT_STRING = "0.00"
```

or

```
FORMAT_STRING = "Fixed"
```

I'm assuming that you didn't *really* want to multiple the value by 100, which is what "Percent" does)

If you *do* want it multiplied by 100, then do that in the expression:

```
     MEMBER [Date].[Percentage] AS 
          100 * ([Date].[AverageSaleNumberThisYear] - [Date].[AverageSaleNumberPreviouseYear] ) / [Date].[AverageSaleNumberThisYear].
```

Comment: then it returns 0.00 instead of 0.40

Comment: @Timsen So you _do_ want to multiple it by 100?  Then do that multiplication in the expression, not in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the technique used in z:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    -0.003989113 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = "Fixed" 
  MEMBER [Measures].[y] AS 
    -0.003989113 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = "0.00" 
  MEMBER [Measures].[z] AS 
    Round(-0.003989113*100,2) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[x]
   ,[Measures].[y]
   ,[Measures].[z]
  } ON 0
FROM [AdventureWorks];
```